Library use on Chol Ha'moed: assisted checkout vs. self-checkout
Using a computer printer may or may not be allowed on Chol Ha'moed, depending on the situation.
Imagine that you're borrowing some books from the public library on Chol Ha'moed.  You have two options.
A.) You can ask a staff member to check the books out for you. They are almost surely non-Jewish. But, if you forget to verbally request "no receipt", they might print a due-date receipt for you without asking.
B.) Or you can use the self-checkout machine. The machine will ask you if you want a receipt, and you can just tap "No".
Which is best:  assisted checkout or self-checkout?
Edit
Is there anything I can do to improve this question?
Related

Can you borrow library books on Chol Ha'moed?.
Returning library books on Chol Hamoed.

